# Generating PDFs from template files using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, html, templates, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I need to generate PDF files from HTML templates and plan on using `wkhtmltopdf` to do that. Inside the HTML templates, I need to be able to use PHP logic to adjust what the template will render. Take this HTML template for example:

```
<p>Dear <?php echo $firstname; ?>,</p>

<p>Thanks for signing up. You've invited these people along with you:</p>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($invitees as $invitee): ?>
        <li><?php echo $invitee; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Chris White</p>
```

I have no problem being able to pass a HTML template file to `wkhtmltopdf` but I don't know how to get the PHP logic inside it to run correctly and be able to return the resulting template. I came across this blog post while Googling but the author uses Smarty as a template language: https://davejamesmiller.com/blog/php-html-pdf-conversion-using-wkhtmltopdf

Using Smarty would solve my problem but I don't want to bring in a library to do this when I can just use plain old PHP. Basically, I need a way to pass in variables to the HTML template (in this case `$firstname` and `$invitees`), have it execute the PHP code inside the template and then return the resulting template after the PHP has been executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just save your file as php (for example template.php) and implement there the logic you need.

I did the same also with wkhtmltopdf and it worked great. 
I also passed some variables over GET to the template to really get the correct report as pdf.

To save the file I used the PHP session id and saved the file to a folder with write permissions for www-data (Linux) and started the download automatically via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and I did it like that. Don t really know if my code will help you but why not.

First I used composer to get https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf.

lets say you have a php file " content.php "

```
<?php 
echo "<html>";
echo "<h1>test</h1>";
echo "<html>";
?>
```

your index.php will be :

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

ob_start();

require('content.php'); //The php file

$content = ob_get_clean();

$pdf = new \mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf($content);
if (!$pdf->send()) {
    throw new Exception('OMG WHY : '.$pdf->getError());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're not using any template engine, can't u just call your template.php file with some params ?

Something like

```
$wkhtml2pdf->html2pdf('template.php?firstname=Foo');
```

(I have no idea how wkhtml2pdf works, this code is just for you to understand the logic)

and in your template.php file :

```
<p>Dear <?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?>,</p>
```